# Spring Annotation trailing slash

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have a controller with `@RequestMapping` for root path `"/"`. There are other controllers with say a `@RequestMapping` of `"/test"` etc. My application seems to be mapping correctly for paths like `/appname/test`, but if I add a trailing slash to the path, like so `"/appname/test/` then it maps to the controller that has the `@RequestMapping` for root path `"/"`. Any idea why?

**Update:**

I also tried removing `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and replacing with

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"
   p:order="0" p:alwaysUseFullPath="true" /> 
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" 
   p:alwaysUseFullPath="true"/>
```

That fixed the trailing slash problem, but my validations stopped working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug ([SPR-7064](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-7064)), fixed in 3.0.3, should be out soon.

Comment: hmm, wondering how petclinic sample works okay! It was built with 3.0.0. My app is on 3.0.2, maybe I will go back to 3.0.0

Comment: @Eqbal: Alternatively, you could add more path mappings as a workaround. `@RequestMapping` can take multiple paths.

Comment: That does not work, anything with a trailing slash maps to root.